# Thread Is impersonating: False while <identity impersonate="true" />

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, impersonation

I'm having trouble diagnosing an anomaly in an application. It works fine in development and test, but doesn't work in preproduction.

I get an access denied error and I suppose it is because the thread isn't impersonating the current user.
This is the log I have

```
Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 01/02/2016 10:54:17
Event time (UTC): 01/02/2016 09:54:17
Event ID: b924fd2c31b44bb59f5e9b9b79f9afc6
Event sequence: 28
Event occurrence: 5
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/SPApp/girsmt-3-130987927149445639
    Trust level: Full
    Application Virtual Path: /SPApp/girsmt
    Application Path: \IIS-CERT\WebAppExt\SPApp\girsmt\
    Machine name: D3IISFEC01

Process information:
    Process ID: 26980
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\girsmt

Exception information:
    Exception type: WebException
    Exception message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
at Generali.SharePoint.Security.SPClientSecurityProvider.CreateContext()
at Generali.Security.SecurityContext.CreateFrom(ContextConfiguration config)
at Generali.Security.SecurityContext..ctor(ContextConfiguration config)
at HierarchyDA.DataAccess.Hierarchy..ctor(SecurityProvider securityProvider, String HierarchyId, String connectionString, String siteUrl)
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.DocumentHierarchyController.get_Hierarchy()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.DocumentHierarchyController.get_CurrentUserGroups()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.get_Permissions()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.CanDo(Permission permission, Policy policy)
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.CanEditSystemTables()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.TopMenuController.CanUseSeeAdminMenu()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GeneralCounsel.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Request information:
    Request URL: https://webappextcert.generali.com:443/spapp/girsmt/pages/admin/update.aspx?SPHostUrl=http://corpcert.generali.com/sites/GGC/girsmt&SPLanguage=en-US&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15.0.4569.1000
    Request path: /spapp/girsmt/pages/admin/update.aspx
    User host address: 10.180.71.189
    User: CORPGEN\e3mpozz2
    Is authenticated: True
    Authentication Type: NTLM
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\girsmt

Thread information:
    Thread ID: 2086
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\girsmt
    Is impersonating: False
    Stack trace:    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
at Generali.SharePoint.Security.SPClientSecurityProvider.CreateContext()
at Generali.Security.SecurityContext.CreateFrom(ContextConfiguration config)
at Generali.Security.SecurityContext..ctor(ContextConfiguration config)
at HierarchyDA.DataAccess.Hierarchy..ctor(SecurityProvider securityProvider, String HierarchyId, String connectionString, String siteUrl)
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.DocumentHierarchyController.get_Hierarchy()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.DocumentHierarchyController.get_CurrentUserGroups()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.get_Permissions()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.CanDo(Permission permission, Policy policy)
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.PermissionsController.CanEditSystemTables()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.BusinessLayer.Controllers.TopMenuController.CanUseSeeAdminMenu()
at GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GeneralCounsel.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Custom event details:
```

and this is the the web config

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <globalization uiCulture="it" culture="it-IT" />
</system.web>
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=" />
    <add key="IssuerId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GIRSAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
    <service name="GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GIRS">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GIRSAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="GEN.AG.GIRSMT.AppWeb.GIRS" />
    </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by app for SharePoint-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PersistenceDBContext" connectionString="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
    <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://webappextcert.generali.com" />
    </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

As you can see the web config has identity impersonate="true" but in the log I still see "Is Impersonating: False"
What am I missing?

Comment: I would do a diff on the files for each environment that works and 1 that doesnt. As you say it works in test but not production. So find out how production is setup different

Comment: Unfortunatly those two environments are quite different... but still is worth a try. thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?